# Nginx and Apache2 (proxy server)

Tags: nginx, apache2

I have nginx and apache2 in the same Ubuntu Server 14.04 and i want to use nginx as proxy server. My idea is when people write www.mysite.com or www2.mysite.com redirect to apache where i have the respective two sites.

Nginx is in port 80 and Apache is in port 81.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
server {
        listen   80; 

        root /var/www/; 
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name example.com www.example.com www1.example.com; 

        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81;

         }

         location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Hope that will give you idea .